# ANGULAR NGXS: How to use selectSnapshot with lazy selector

Tags: angular, typescript, state-management, ngxs

I am learning NGXS, I have a lazy selector as below

```
@Selector()
static getStudent(state: StudentModel) {
    return (std_id: string) => {
        return state.students[std_id];
    } 
}
```

in component, I tried to get a snapshot of that selector

```
let _student = this.store.selectSnapshot(StudentState.getStudent);
console.log('_student : ', JSON.stringify(_student ));
```

But the result is `undefined`

Any Suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning a value but a function declaration

```js
this.store.selectSnapshot(StudentState.getStudent);
```

you may want to define an ngxs [dynamic selector](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#dynamic-selectors) which takes arguments, like std_id, and process the desired value in selector body definition and by using dynamic selectors do not define selector decorator.
Then;

```js
this.store.selectSnapshot(StudentState.getStudent(std_id));
```

snapshots are static, you should use @Select decorator and subscribe to it on your component;

```
@Select(StudentState.getStudent(std_id))
getStudent$: Observable<SomeMOdel>;

ngOnit() {
   this.getStudent$.subscribe(console.log);
}

// or
```

```html
<div *ngIf="getStudent$ | async as student">{{ student }}</div>
```

Comment: is std_id a variable ? if I updated it from template, the state will be also updated?